# How do Formtastic and simple_form compare?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

How do [Formtastic](https://github.com/formtastic/formtastic) and [simple_form](https://github.com/heartcombo/simple_form) compare?
What are the pros and cons of each?

Comment: Ryan bates axplained both in his Railscast [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/184-formtastic-part-1) and [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/234-simple-form). He also quickly explains some differences in the SimpleForm cast

Answer (score 69, accepted):

[Formtastic](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic) and [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) are very similar, the usage is also very similar.

The main difference is that the markup of `formtastic` is fixed. Mind you: if you don't mind, it is fantastic. It is really awesome to get started with. Also it comes with a default css, so your forms will look good straight out of the box.

The advantage of `simple_form` over `formtastic` is that you can modify the markup to your needs. This can be handy if your designer likes your fields to be grouped inside div instead of li. The downside of `simple_form` is that it doesn't come with any standard layout (css). That makes formtastic much easier to start off with. Because the API is nearly identical, if needed, you can very easily switch to `simple_form` if needed.

[UPDATE 22-6-2015] Actually, currently simple-form supports bootstrap out of the box, so for me personally I always prefer simple-form now.

[UPDATE 29-07-2014] simple_form added an option of being compatible with ZURB Foundation forms.

Comment: Note that since this answer was written, simple_form has added a mode that generates appropriate markup for Twitter Bootstrap; all you have to do is drop in the CSS files and flip a switch to get pretty forms.

Comment: Also the main difference is that there are no group DSL in simple_form, like inputs or actions.

Comment: @James How to make simple_form compatible with bootstrap ? See  [this railscast episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/329-more-on-twitter-bootstrap), around 3:11

Comment: In addition to differences related to CSS & grouping, a couple of input types are a little different. Formtastic calls "numeric" "number". Additionally, :currency is not available in Formtastic, unlike simple_form.

Comment: Personally, I think simple_form is way ahead of formtastic. I was forced to use formtastic when building customisations to an active_admin dashboard. The gem is not easily extendible by a long shot. Stick to simple_form.

Comment: One should check the number of issues. Currently simple-form has 5x more than formtastic, the same with the pull requests.

Answer (score 7):

At the moment, simple_form with Twitter Bootstrap 3 is a pain. But it works very well with BS2. Formtastic and BS3 work very well through the `formtastic-bootstrap` gem:

`gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.0.3.0'`

`gem 'formtastic-bootstrap', git: 'https://github.com/mjbellantoni/formtastic-bootstrap.git', branch: :bootstrap3_and_rails4`

Unfortunately, Formtastic does not handle `rails g scaffold`; simple_form does.